# One fixed width DIV in center, and two other on both sides (taking all rest place of screen)?

Tags: html, css

Is that possible to do that only with HTML and CSS? Of cource, screen width can be various.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this with `display:table` property. write like this:

```
.parent{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.parent div{
    display:table-cell
}
.middle{
    width:300px;
    background:red;
}
.left{
    background:green;
}
.right{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QUVeq/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like in that example

http://jsfiddle.net/HCFpE/

add the `width: auto;` to your #left and #right css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HCFpE/1/ Changing of content brings to changing of #left and #right width..

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    float:left; 
}
#left{
    width:20%;
    float:left; 
}
#center{
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
#right{
    width:20%;
    float:right;    
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```